# Xamarin: Pop modal form after another modal form was pushed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog

I have a problem to remove a modal from the stack after another modal was pushed.
I have a content page where the user can select a product. Clicking on the ListView opens a modal form with product details. On this modal form is a button to add the product to a wishlist which opens a new modal form for the wishlist details. I want to close the first modal form after the new modal form was launched.
Here is the sample code:

```
private async void Btn_addToWishlist_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            
            var item = sender as Button;
            if(Controllers.CurrentProductModel == "Products")
            {
                AllProducts product = item.BindingContext as AllProducts;
                var nextpage = new WishlistSelectorPopupPage
                {
                    BindingContext = product
                };
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nextpage);
            }
            else if(Controllers.CurrentProductModel == "AllProducts")
            {
                AllProducts product = item.BindingContext as AllProducts;
                var nextpage = new WishlistSelectorPopupPage
                {
                    BindingContext = product
                };
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nextpage);
            }
            
            Navigation.RemovePage(this);
           
        }
```

The last line "Navigation.RemovePage(this)" brings an error because it is a modal page.
How can I adress to remove or pop a specific modal page?

Answer (score 0):

would this help?

```
var previousPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomPage());
Navigation.RemovePage(previousPage);
```

or

```
var _navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation; 
var lastPage = _navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault(); 

_navigation.RemovePage(lastPage);
```

Comment: Good idea. Now I get the following error: RemovePage is not supported globally on Windows, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: on runtime?............

Comment: i compile them both working

Comment: Yes, for both the same error. Could it be that the error occurs because it is a modal page I want to remove? Any yes: At runtime

Comment: are you doing this on the first page you load in the MainPage?

Comment: your problem is because you didn't put your mainpage as a navigation page. Go to app.cs and change it to this:   MainPage = new NavigationPage( new YourPage());

Comment: Thanks Amjad but both is not working. I changed my code and changed the pages to normal pages and all works but I need both pages to be Modal Pages which causes the problem. The modal pages have an own stack and remove page from a modal stack doesnt work. So in your sample it would not be "await Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomPage());" but "Navigation.PusModalAsync(new CustomPage());"

Comment: why you want it to be modelpage? do you know the difference between it and pushing a normal page?

Comment: The user should be force to insert data and should not be able to use the back button. That's why these are modal pages. But it seems that whats running well with RG.POPUPs is not possible within Xamarin modal pages. Seems I have to rebuild the whole stuff into navigation forms

Comment: okay so you can simply do a navigationpage and then disable the navigation bar. put this in xaml of the page NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" or in code befind in c#  NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);